# $F$ does not equal $t^2$?

Tags: anova, t-test, degrees-of-freedom

I did a two-way ANOVA and looked at the interaction effect of gender and age. I found $F$-values for the three age-groups. I focused on one specific age-group.

Then I had to compare the $F$-value to an independent samples $t$-test that I did for the same age-group, comparing the mean of men to the mean of women.

$F$ should equal $t^2$, but the assignment already stated that the $F$-value that I would find doesn't equal the $t^2$ value and it asks me to explain why not.

I think it has something to do with different degrees of freedom, but I'm not entirely sure. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask essentially the same question. Edit the original instead to incorporate the changes in wording.

Comment: Please explain why you think "$F$ should equal $t^2$."  What are the assumptions needed for that to hold?  I hope that by making that effort you will uncover the reasons why your expectation is incorrect.

Comment: I think I figured it out already, I simply overlooked the fact that an ANOVA and independent samples t-test are the same only when the ANOVA compares 2 groups, which was really stupid of me. Even though I focus on one age-group containing 2 groups, a male and female group, the ANOVA is still carried out comparing 6 groups in total and therefore the value of F differs.